# MySQL query to Track records from History table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I need to know logic in mysql query to track history of all changes. The below example will explain my expectation.

`account` table

```
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | emailid | created_date        | modified_date       |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | abc     | 2020-03-20 00:00:00 | 2020-07-10 00:00:00 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

`account_history` table

```
+------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | emailid | modified_date       |
+------+---------+---------------------+
|    1 | def     | 2020-04-03 00:00:00 |
|    1 | ghi     | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 |
|    1 | lmn     | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |
|    1 | opq     | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 |
|    1 | opq     | 2020-07-03 00:00:00 |
|    1 | qrs     | 2020-07-10 00:00:00 |
+------+---------+---------------------+
```

Expected result

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id   | parameter | oldvalue | newvalue | event             | event_datetime      |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | emailid   | NULL     | def      | New Entry         | 2020-03-20 00:00:00 |
|    1 | emailid   | def      | ghi      | Change in account | 2020-04-03 00:00:00 |
|    1 | emailid   | ghi      | lmn      | Change in account | 2020-05-05 00:00:00 |
|    1 | emailid   | lmn      | opq      | Change in account | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |
|    1 | emailid   | opq      | qrs      | Change in account | 2020-07-03 00:00:00 |
|    1 | emailid   | qrs      | abc      | Change in account | 2020-07-10 00:00:00 |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I have main table called `account` and history table called `account_history`. Every changes in account will be tracked in its history table and the current values will be stored in history table. I am expecting my output to be like this. And if there is no change occured, no need to track that. I am having logic to track on a daily basis. But I wanted to track it for the past data.
Track on daily basis query,

```
mysql>  select id,'emailid',acch.emailid as oldvalue,acc.emailid as newvalue,'Change in account',acc.modified_date from account acc join account_history acch using(id) where acc.emailid!=acch.emailid and acc.modified_date=acch.modified_date;
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id   | emailid | oldvalue | newvalue | Change in account | modified_date       |
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | emailid | qrs      | abc      | Change in account | 2020-07-10 00:00:00 |
+------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Feeling difficulty in tracking for past data. Help me on this.

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23

Even more than 1 or 2 queries to arrive at the solution would be helpful. By creating any intermediate tables and arriving at the solution would be helpful.

Comment: It's helpful to know what version of mysql you are working with.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23

Comment: The value of `modified_date` in account is earlier than the last change in account_history ?

Comment: Sorry, that's by mistake. Will update it

Comment: I don't understand whty the event date for def is 03-20 when it actually seemed to be 04-03

Comment: Let me clear on that, new customer got entered at 03-20 with value `def`. And its value got changed to `ghi` on 04-03. So in history table its old value will be maintained as `def` and modified_date as 04-03. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: `opq` was replaced with `opq` accordint account history? is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is no change right. so, in the result we can ignore that. That's why I included these case.

Comment: Before I work on this please confirm that history only tracks emailid - if not then your sample date is not representative of the actual data and should be amended so that it is representative..

Comment: history tables also tracks multiple parameters. That's why I have added the case like emailid unchanged on particular date, so two entries for that where another parameters may have changed.

Comment: Then your sample data is not representative and I have no clear idea if your history table has 1 row per column changed or many columns per row changed so I will drop out for now.

Comment: I don't wanted to make multiple columns in my sample data which ll create more confusion, that's why I gave sample like this. History table will have 1 row per column changed. I am not sure why you say my sample data is not representative. Anyway,thanks.

Comment: @P.Salmon And if you wanted to give a try, you can leave that unchanged inserts and provide a solution.

Comment: Your sample data is not representative because if you have 1 row per column change I would expect the table to look more like id, column_changed, column_value, modified_date . Your data has id,emailid(value),modified_date. It would be clearer if you published your table definitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218029/discussion-between-priya-m-and-p-salmon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have no ability to optimise table structure. So, the main idea is to do the following:

1. Transform initial data to sequential list of modifications.
2. Join this list with itself where new value record's sequence number has the next sequence number relatively old value record's sequence number.

The solution for MySQL 5.7 described as two stage query for simplicity. This can be done more simple in MySQL 8. Also, this is not elegant solution but simple to explain approach.

Step 1. Sequential list.

```sql
-- The variable to create sequential number
SET @rn := 0;

SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 as rn,
       ah.*
FROM (
    -- Add history record for creating new entry
    SELECT id, null as emailid, 'New Entry' as event, created_date as modified_date
    FROM account

    UNION
    -- Add intermediate history records
    -- Need grouping to filter identical values (like 'opq')
    SELECT id, emailid, 'Change in account' as event, min(modified_date) as modified_date
    FROM account_history GROUP BY id, emailid

    UNION

    -- Add history record for current value
    SELECT id, emailid, 'Change in account' as event, modified_date
    FROM account
) as ah,
  (SELECT @row := 0) as r

ORDER BY id, modified_date;
```

This query results in the following list:

```
rn  id  emailid  event              modified_date
 1   1  NULL     New Entry          2020-03-20 00:00:00
 2   1  def      Change in account  2020-04-03 00:00:00
 3   1  ghi      Change in account  2020-05-05 00:00:00
 4   1  lmn      Change in account  2020-06-05 00:00:00
 5   1  opq      Change in account  2020-07-01 00:00:00
 6   1  qrs      Change in account  2020-07-10 00:00:00
 7   1  abc      Change in account  2020-07-10 00:00:00
```

Step 2. Self-join sequential list.

Suppose above list is named `subquery` (subquery, view, temporary table, etc.). Join it in the following way:

```sql
SELECT s1.id,
       'emailid' as emailid,
       s1.emailid as oldvalue,
       s2.emailid as newvalue,
       s1.event,
       s1.modified_date
FROM subquery as s1
    JOIN subquery as s2
        ON s2.id = s1.id AND s2.rn = s1.rn + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Serg. This query worked perfectly for my version.